# Удаление программ в Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

У меня неоднократно возникают проблемы с уделением программ в linux. Именно программ. Например для установки требуется определенное колличество места а при удалении показывает что освободится совсем другое колличество места. Например устанавливаю программу на 50 мб а при удалении пишет что освободится только например 15мб. Что это значит? Как удалять программы до конца? Сколько установил, столько и удалил. Удаляю обычно вот так: `apt-get --purge remove`
И вот еще одна нестыковка:

```
# apt-get --purge remove chromium-browser
Чтение списков пакетов… 
Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… 
Готово
Следующие пакеты устанавливались автоматически и больше не требуются:
linux-headers-4.15.0-20 
linux-headers-4.15.0-20-generic
linux-image-4.15.0-20-generic 
linux-modules-4.15.0-20-generic
linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-20-generic
Для их удаления используйте «apt autoremove».
Пакеты, которые будут УДАЛЕНЫ:
  chromium-browser* chromium-browser-l10n*
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, 
для удаления отмечено 2 пакетов, и 10 пакетов не обновлено.
После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства уменьшится на 224 MB.
Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] y
```

Что значит "**уменьшится**"? Я же удаляю, должно наоборот увеличится. Разве нет?
И могу ли я быть уверен что `apt-get --purge remove` Удалит все точно как надо и без остатков?

Comment: объём ***занятого*** дискового пространства уменьшится

Comment: «...освободится только например 15мб» — у каждой программы есть какие-то зависимости, при удалении программы зависимости не удаляются, хотите удалять зависимости — используйте autoremove

Comment: Думаю проблема тут что вы удаляете не **программы** (/bin/ls /bin/cp) а **пакеты** с полным букетом зависимостей от библиотек.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

После `apt purge programname` нужно выполнить `apt autoremove` для удаления всех неиспользуемых более зависимостей. Затем можно выполнить `apt clean`, очистив тем самым кэш пакетов в `/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Comment: Вдогонку: http://myubuntu.ru/rukovodstvo/25-poleznykh-bazovykh-komand-apt-get-i-apt-cache-chast-3